# How do I put widgets inside a frame inside a window?

Tags: python, tkinter

so I'm trying to put together an GUI divided up into multiple frames, and then have each frame have either labels or inputs, however, on the 'inputframe', whenever I add the label and try to place it, it just plops the label in the middle of the frame and I can't seem to move it anywhere. Is it possible for me to place labels inside a frame how I like?

I'm doing this on VS Code, have made progress on every other problem I've run into so far but can't seem to solve this one.

```
class Window1:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk() # Create a window
        window.title("Order Processing Application") # Set title of a window
        window.geometry('920x560')

        #set up window and import picture for the window
        photo = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\GWlogo.gif")

        logoFrame = Frame(window, width = 160, height = 160)
        logoFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        stepTitleFrame = Frame(window, width = 840, height = 160, bg = 'red')
        stepTitleFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        statusFrame = Frame(window, width = 320, height = 560, bg='green')
        statusFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        inputFrame = Frame(window, width = 840, height = 560)
        inputFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        #imports Glamping World logo into the logo frame
        logoPic = Label(logoFrame, image = photo)
        logoPic.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        #Testing labels in the main input frame
        inputLabel1 = Label(inputFrame, text="Testing Label 1")
        inputLabel1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
```

I'm trying to get the label to appear in the inputFrame, row 0 column 0, but it will only appear in the middle of the inputFrame.

[image: Here's what I keep getting]

Comment: select code and use button `{}` to correctly format it. Add tag `python` and it will be colored.

Comment: create minimal working example with this problem so we could run it and see problem. And don't use images - we don't have your images.

Comment: it is natural that you get it in the middle. Y can use `grid(sticky=...)` to align it - ie `sticky="w"` (west/left). See [align-grid-pack](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/align-grid-pack)

Comment: inside `inputFrame` you can always use `pack()` or `place()` instead of `grid()`